# Active Directory modifications using SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've exported my AD into CSV and pumped it into SQL, the goal is to modify some fields and import it back into AD.

I've done every field I need to do except one, the proxyAddress field.

My data looks like this:

```
proxyAddresses
sip:john.smiths@email.com;SMTP:john.smith@email.com
sip:james.jones@email.com;SMTP:james.jones@email.com;notes:james.jones/EMAIL/
```

etc...

I'm trying to change the `sip:` values, but as they're all different username, and have SMTP included, I'm struggling with the SQL LIKE command.

I need to data to look like this:

```
proxyAddresses
sip:john.smiths@newemail.com;SMTP:john.smith@email.com
sip:james.jones@newemail.com;SMTP:james.jones@email.com;notes:james.jones/EMAIL/
```

Changing the `sip:` value, but leaving the rest as they are.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

We don't know the tables definition nor the mapping between new and old values, so just for the start something like this:

```
declare @e varchar(1000) = 'sip:james.jones@email.com;SMTP:james.jones@email.com;notes:james.jones/EMAIL/'
declare @newEmail varchar(126) = 'james.jones@newemail.com'

select stuff(@e, charindex(':', @e)+1, charindex(';', @e)-charindex(':', @e)-1, @newEmail)
```

Comment: Hi dean, I've been toying with your suggestion. The problem I'm having is the large amount of objects I have in my AD(6000+). I can't fingure out how to make the delcarations variables, so I'm not just changes james.jones's value

Comment: Could you provide us a sample to work with? You probably have a table with the original values, and a table with mapping from old to new values, or some algorithm to do this.

Comment: I have a table with all my AD details in it, and a table with users phone numbers, e-mail addresses and mobile numbers. I am using SQL to clean this data up, correct the format and join the tables together (On e maill addresses) so I can create an LDFIDE file to import it back into AD. The only column I can't do is the one stated above. The data displayed there is how it comes from AD.

Comment: I can't help you without table definitions and some sample data. You can use http://sqlfiddle.com/ to create a sample.